# How do I reuse ajax factory method to setup a $scoped variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a repeating piece of code that pops up in my controllers:

```
// Get first product from list
Product.get_details( id )
  .success(function ( data ) {

    // Setup product details
    $scope.active_product = data;

  });
```

I want to put this into a factory so I can DRY my code.

The problem happens when I need to access `$scope.active_product` and have it watched by the digest loop.

#### Inside Product factory:

```
  //  ajax function returns product data
  var get_details = function( id ){ ... }

  var set_active_product = function( active_product, id ){

    // Get first product from list
    get_details( id )
      .success(function ( data ) {

        // Setup product details
        active_product = data;

      });

  };
```

#### And inside my controller

```
Product.set_active_product( $scope.active_product, id );
```

This works but `$scope` is not being monitored by the `$digest` loop.

Is there a way to do this without passing in a `$scop`ed variable?

Comment: what about using $resource? $scope.active_product = Product.get(); looks awesome

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Yes! Thanks a lot for that. Just shows how poor angular's documentation is. `$resource` cuts down half my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PetrAveryanov for pointing out [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Use $resource to get the data and initially populate the `$scope.active_product` with an empty object. That means that `active_product` only shows when it's populated by `$resource`.

#### Inside Product factory

```
return $resource('/path/to/resource');
```

#### Inside controller

```
$scope.active_product = Product.get({ id: id });
```